# Как из js коллекции обратиться к элементу над которым произошло событие?

Tags: javascript, dom

На HTML странице есть список с одинаковыми классами.

Необходимо чтобы при клике по любому из элементов списка, этот элемент менял фоновый цвет.

```
<ul>
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
</ul>
```

Я могу сохранить коллекцию в переменную, но как потом узнать, по какому именно из элементов совершен клик?

Если обращаюсь с индексом `but[1]`, то все работает. Естественно, я не могу присвоить свойство всей коллекции.

Подскажите, что добавить или исправить в коде?

```
var but = document.querySelectorAll('.list-group-item');
but.onclick = function() {
  but.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно на каждый элемент повесить обработчик события `click`. Например, с помощью цикла

```js
var but = document.querySelectorAll('.list-group-item');

for (i = 0, len = but.length; i < len; i++) {
  but[i].onclick = function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  };
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Святая корова! Спасибо тебе большое, милый человек)
Я знал что нужно обработать коллекцию как массив, но КАК это сделать не понимал.

Comment: Ну тогда и небольшой оффтоп. Почему мы заранее определяем переменную len в данном случае: (var i = 0, len = but.length; i < len; i++).
Чем не хорош такой вариант: (var i = 0; i < but.length; i++)?

Comment: Длина массива `length` вычисляется каждый раз. Чтобы улучшить производительность, мы запоминаем значение в переменной. Это особенно важно для массивов DOM элементов, как в нашем случае. [Тест](https://jsperf.com/testing-loops-over-dom-nodes)

Answer (score 4):

немного улучшим ответ **Dmitry**
сделаем все лаконичней

```js
var buts = document.querySelectorAll('.list-group-item');

buts.forEach(but => {
  but.onclick = () => { but.style.backgroundColor = 'red';};
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Если так то уже тогда можно document.querySelectorAll('.list-group-item').forEach(but =>  but.onclick = () => but.style.backgroundColor = 'red');

Comment: не понял что значит это часть кода?<code>but => </code> чему должен быть равен(или больше) переменная but там же после него уже кавычка стоит.

Comment: @DuuudeXX8 это стрелочная функция ()=>{} появившаяся в es6

Comment: Спасибо большое